# javafx combobox dropdown go out from the edges of the screen

Tags: java, combobox, javafx

I have the last version of java(8_40) and javaFX.

I have a checkbox with 10 items.
I compile and run the program.
If i move the program window to the bottom of the monitor screen, the dropdown list go out from the monitor screen. It is impossible to click the items out the screen.

Instead, if I try to do the same layout with scenes builder 2.0, click on preview, the dropdown is moved automatically up for not exit the screen.

Why with scenes builder is properly displayed, instead with "compile and run" not?

The problem is the same that if I do graphics via code is that if I use the files fxml.

I put below a small program example that gives me this error:

**Component CustomControl.java**

```
public class CustomControl extends VBox {

    public CustomControl() {
        ComboBox<String> asd = new ComboBox<String>();

        ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();       
        asd.setItems(data);

        data.add("1");
        data.add("2");
        data.add("3");
        data.add("4");
        data.add("5");
        data.add("6");
        data.add("7");
        data.add("8");
        data.add("9");
        data.add("10");

        getChildren().add(asd);
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class CustomControlExample extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }       
    String address = " ";

    @Override public void start(Stage stage) {
        stage.setTitle("ComboBoxSample");
        Scene scene = new Scene(new CustomControl());        

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

Screen-shot on the left the pop-up go out of the screen border (eclipse)
While, on the right the pop-up is automatically moved (Scene builder)

[image]

Comment: The dropdown popup go out of the screen monitor. It is impossible to click on the not visible list

Comment: Interesting, I tried it and get the same behavior as Nicolò.  Test system was OS X 10.9 + Java 8u40 or SceneBuilder 2.0-b20 which runs on an embedded Java 1.8.0-b132.  I believe it is a regression in functionality.  I advise [filing a bug report](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com).

Comment: Seems like a bug in `Java 8 update 40` release. I can reproduce the issue in Ubuntu 14.04 + Java 8u40. The interesting part is I tried it on Java 8u25 and things run fine in it. The pop up, when it doesn't have enough space in the bottom, is shown on the top of the combobox.

Comment: a screenshot of the problem http://s2.postimg.org/yo1e6iwc9/aaaaaa.jpg

Comment: @Nicolò I have filed a [bug report](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-40302). You can vote it and keep a watch on it for changes and fixes. :)

Comment: @ItachiUchiha Thankyou for report. Voted! :) hopefully they solve the problem. Can you add to Environment Windows 8.1+Java 8u40? thanks

Comment: I suppose the fix will be released in the next version 8u60. There is a release date of 8u60? Until 8u60 release how I can solve the problem in my program? There are patches to use or something else to use in the meantime?

Comment: @Nicolò, Did you ever get an answer to your patches question?  I'm looking for the same.

Answer (score 0):

See this image:

[image]

It is easy to solve, just change the visible row count.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I Post the link because site ask me that i must have 10 reputation

Comment: "It is easy to solve, just change the visible row count.". This is not a real world solution.