# JavaFX Combobox drop-down menu gets cut off screen

Tags: java, combobox, javafx

In an application that I am developing, I have recently come across an issue with the JavaFX Combobox dropping in a fashion that makes go off of the screen. This is not an issue when the application is used in a small window, since there is space below the window for the drop-down to go. However, when the window is at the bottom of the screen, it gets partly cut off. See images below:

[image: dropdown is cut off]

At first I believed the issue to be due to my custom cell renderer which allows an image to be shown as well as text, however the official JavaFX 'Modena' demo experiences the same issues. The Combobox should display A-F:

[image: combo box display cut off]

On further investigation I tested the application on a public computer and it appears that the Combobox exhibits the correct behaviour in a lower version of Java 8. I was not able to check the Java version, or take a screenshot, but the Combobox menu appeared **above** the main box, thus solving the issue.

How would I go about fixing this behaviour?

Comment: What version of Java are you using?

Comment: I am currently using Java 8.45

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue that was injected in Java 8u40 release. It was [reported](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-40302) and was fixed for Java 8u60 release.

You can find the relevant discussion in the comments section for the question [javafx combobox dropdown go out from the edges of the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29127272/javafx-combobox-dropdown-go-out-from-the-edges-of-the-screen).